# Swift - How to update custom cell label from UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, delegates

I have a custom collection view cell subclass with a title label. I want to change the title label of the cell, to the title of the selected action in the action sheet. I tried doing this in the handler, but I cannot access the cells label through the handler.

Here is the code for the action sheet

```
func dailyInjuryIllnessActionSheet() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Select an Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        //alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Available for Full Participation", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Available for Full Participation", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
            /// Change the cell text - Get the `UILabel`, and replace the text with `action.title`
            

        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Available for Limited Participation", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Not Available For Participation", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close Injury / Illness", style: .default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And here is the code for the cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DIISDetailCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? DIISDetailCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }
        if let entries = player?.entries {
            for entry in entries {
                cell.eventName.text = entry.injuryIllnessName
                cell.eventDate.text = entry.statusDate.formatted()
                cell.eventType.text = entry.status
                cell.modifiedBy.text = entry.modifiedBy ?? "Modified By Goes Here"
                
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

I have been stuck on this all week.

Where I call the code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        dailyInjuryIllnessActionSheet()
    }
```

Comment: Where do you call `dailyInjuryIllnesActionSheet`?

Comment: I call it in didSelectItemAt @paulw11

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code. You can pass the cell to the function or you could pass a completion handler to the function and update the label in the completion handler

Comment: I just fixed my question. Can you please show me what you mean if you have time? The UILabel is defined the the cell subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update your model data (and subsequently your cell label) once the user has made a selection from the alert.  The alert choice is made *asynchronously*.  There are a couple of common approaches you could use.  One is delegation.  The other is to pass a completion handler closure.  The second is more *Swifty* and is what I will use.

First, you have an error in your `cellForItemAt` - It will be called for each cell, so you shouldn't have a `for` loop - You need to access the required element based on the `IndexPath.item`.  This is one function where you typically will use a force downcast and a force unwrap, since the cell class needs to be registered and your `numberOfItems` function should return 0 if you have no entries (or no `player`) -

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: DIISDetailCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DIISDetailCell
    let entry = player!.entries[indexPath.item]
    cell.eventName.text = entry.injuryIllnessName
    cell.eventDate.text = entry.statusDate.formatted()
    cell.eventType.text = entry.status
    cell.modifiedBy.text = entry.modifiedBy ?? "Modified By Goes Here"
               
    return cell
}
```

You can simplify your `dailyInjuryIllnessActionSheet` code a little by using an array for the options.  For simplicity I have declared the array in the function, but it should probably be passed in from some other information source.

Add a `completion` handler parameter to this function to pass the selected option back to the caller:

```
func dailyInjuryIllnessActionSheet(completion:((String?)->Void)?=nil) {
    
    let options = ["Available for Full Participation",
                   "Available for Limited Participation",
                   "Not Available For Participation",
                   "Close Injury / Illness"
    ]
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Select an Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    
    for option in options {
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: option, style: .default, handler: { action in 
            completion?(option)
        }))
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
        completion?(nil)
    }))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now you can pass a completion handler when you call `dailyInjuryIllnessActionSheet` to update your model and reload the item:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dailyInjuryIllnessActionSheet() { selectedOption in {
        guard let selectedOption = selectedOption else {
            return
        }
        player!.entries[indexPath.item].status = selectedOption
        collectionView.reloadItems(at:[indexPath])
    }
  
}
```